# CRM 2011 - unable to connect to database after installing Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm-2011

I've been given a VM for development purposes, in which is installed Windows 2008R2, CRM 2011, SQL Server, etc. Prior to me being given the project, the VM was being used inhouse, validating to the company's AD server.

Since I need to use the VM off-site, I have run "dcpromo" in order to install Active Directory etc. in the VM. As you may have guessed, upon doing this, nothing can now connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication, because users are now AD users, with different IDs (at least I assume that's the problem - I'm no sys admin).

So when I run CRM Deployment Manager, it says it can't connect to the CRM_CONFIG database, assumedly because Windows Auth isn't working. SQL Server is running fine. In fact Windows Auth won't even work in SQL Mgmt Studio, I have to connect using SQL Server Auth.

How do I fix this mess? :) Is there a way of telling CRM Deployment Manager (and everything else) to use SQL Server Auth instead of Windows Auth? Or is there a way to fix Windows Auth on the machine? The latter would be preferable, as it would probably fix everything which now can't connect to SQL Server with Windows Auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to fix this, but I would probably have a go at:

1. Uninstall CRM
2. Reinstall CRM - these steps should give you a working CRM, without any customisations or data.
3. Import the existing organisation - this should give you CRM as the original developers had it (as part of the import process you can remap all the users in AD).

Check out this link for detail on the process:

[Import a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Organization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127042.aspx)

Also this may help:

[Move the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 deployment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699772.aspx#Redploy_CRM_Server)

Comment: Thanks James. Might have to do that.. will take while, so before I do, is there no way to make CRM use SQL Server auth ("sa" login) instead of Windows auth, and change user auth from AD to non-AD? (ie. get rid of AD althogether)?

Comment: +1 Given the way that CRM uses "current user" to build FilteredEntity views, I can't believe that use SQL auth will ever be feasible.