# Possible to move CRM from one Active Directory to another with different users?

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm-2011

A client has a VM in which a staging version of CRM 2011 is installed, for development purposes. It has been used so far at the client's premises, so everything authenticates against the client's own Active Directory setup.

I now need to use this VM outside their network, but of course CRM won't function separated from the AD network.

If I install domain controller, Active Directory, etc. in the VM, is there a way to tell CRM to authenticate using the local AD instead of looking for the client's AD server?

Basically I'd like to make this VM a completely self-contained CRM 2011 install, without having to reinstall CRM from scratch. Is that possible?

Comment: This appears to be a continuation (possible duplicate) of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443634/crm-2011-unable-to-connect-to-database-after-installing-active-directory

Comment: @JamesWood Different question - the other one was asking about Windows auth / SQL auth, but I found it's not possible, so this question is about changing the AD server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by backing up the CRM SQL database and re-importing it on your new environment as a new organisation. During this process you will be able to remap your users.

You should first take a full SQL back-up of the source environment's OrganisationName_MSCRM database. You then need to restore it to the target SQL server just like any other SQL restore. From that point on you can follow [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127042.aspx) which details the steps involved to reconfigure the CRM deployment. It also includes screenshots of the user mapping process.

---

### Edit:

I didn't read the question properly and @JamesWood alerted me to detail there which makes my answer a little inaccurate.

I assumed this was a simple question of "how do I get this CRM data(base) working in a new environment" when in fact the question is more like "how do I move a CRM VM to a different AD and have it work as before".

In the former case, my answer above still stands.

In the latter case, I am not aware of any way of reconfiguring the CRM (VM) server or AD to work in a different environment. Given the steps that the original poster is prepared to consider ("...install domain controller, Active Directory, etc. in the VM...") I think that the best solution is to create a new virgin VM, install CRM and reimport the database as per the first part of my answer.

Thanks to James for the heads-up.

Comment: Will this work if CRM (the product as a whole - not the organisation) was installed against a different AD?

Comment: @JamesWood I'm not sure I follow...? :/

Comment: I don't think @ingredient_15939 is trying to move a CRM organisation between two CRM environments. But is instead trying to move the entire installation of CRM from one AD to another. I'm not sure this is actually achieveable, and I think the answer you - and I in the related question - have given him is the best that can be done. But it requires a fresh install of CRM on a new environment against the new AD, I believe you only get to select the AD Organisational Unit when installing CRM - not when importing organisations. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Oh I see your point and re-reading OP's question you are exactly right James. I'm not sure of the reasoning for specifically wanting to *reuse* the original VM (perhaps this was just an assumption by the OP and we are overstating that point?) - suffice to say, creating a new VM and importing the SQL database as per my answer is the only way I can see this working.

Comment: Thanks very much Greg and @JamesWood, I was just wanting to avoid a re-install if possible, partly because the client isn't even sure where their install media is (long history with this one). If the bottom line is I can't detach this VM from their AD, then I'll mark this answered as such. Thanks again.